# Remove Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority from System Keychain

Tags: certificate, keychain

Since the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority expired on February 14th, I need to install the new one. In order to do so, I have to delete the old one from both System and Login tabs in my keychain.

Removing it from the login tab was easy and instantaneous. But removing it from the System tab is impossible. I can see it in my system tab, stating that it is expired:

[image]

When I try to delete it, I'll get the following error:

[image]

I need to delete it so I could upload apps to the appStore. Meanwhile, I am stuck and can't do anything. What can I do to delete it!?

This is what I always get if I try to unlock the Systems Tab:

[image]

This is what Xcode gives me:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you select view expired certificates on keychain in order to delete the old certificate

Comment: I think the reason that the question has a bounty is that it's on the wrong board. Wouldn't it fit better to Ask Different or SuperUser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer for any future developers having the same problem is really simple :

- Restart your Mac
- While restarting hold on Command + R , this will boot up your mac in the "sudo" mode, allowing you to write bash command. Please note that writing the following command is really safe and risk free, but as always while dealing with systematic commands, make sure your backup is near by!
- When loaded, go to utilities, terminal.
- First, write : `csrutil status` . This will show you the status of SIP. Your goal will be to disable the SIP ( System Integrity Protection ). After checking the status, most likely you will find the status Enabled.
- When you find it enabled, write : `csrutil disable` . This will disable the SIP.
- Restart your mac, open keychain, and you will be capable of deleting any stuck certificate, including the expired WWDR.

Hope it will help someone in the future!!

Answer (score 3):

Try to install new certificate from link below.

https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

This worked for me.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: i installed the new one, but i need to delete the old one because xcode won't let me submit anything to the store

Comment: Try to reset Key Chain from Keychain Access

1. Open Keychain Access
2. Open Preference

Then Click on "Reset My Default Keychain" button and try to reinstall certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You go to Keychain access and right click on Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority now click on delete. [image]

If this is not working then just click on System from left side top and do the same after that drag drop the new certificate that is found : https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Comment: this is what i am doing !! and still im getting the same error

Comment: i tried to delete the certificate, but whatever i do i can't delete it

Comment: Did you check system tab as I faced the same issue yesterday

Comment: the problem is in the system tab, i can't delete anything from the system tab, and it is unlocked for sure but i can't delete anything

Comment: I think you right clicked on system tab just click on it and check on right side .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103704/discussion-between-reshmi-majumder-and-elias-rahme).